# How exactly remove_if() works?

Tags: c++, stl, c++17

I have referred many resources but unable to understand the part about how exactly it  modifies the elements in the container.
I have written some code to try to understand, can anyone explain what is happening?

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

bool test(char c)
{
    return (c=='a');
}

int isPalindrome(string A) 
{
    remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), test);
    cout<<A<<'\n';   
 }

int main() 
{
    
    string A="aaaaabbbbb";
    isPalindrome(A); 

    return 0;
}
```

According to my understanding so far it should move all the a characters to the right of b and if we try to print it we should get

```
bbbbbaaaaa
```

Instead I am getting

```
bbbbbbbbbb
```

Comment: remove_if should just remove them entirely .. not move them

Comment: What's happening is expected behavior. It's checking each element against the predicate and if the condition is true they get removed

Comment: What is the reason behind printing of extra b in the output? @Nina

Comment: It isn't possible for an algorithm to directly use iterators to modify a container. The best `std::remove_if` can do is partition the container such that the remaining elements remain on one side of the partition, and the rest of the container is in some unspecified state. The function returns an iterator which defines the end of the range of valid values. It's up to the function's user to then shrink the container by actually removing everything that comes after that iterator.

Comment: @Scheff -- that's an interesting quotation, because it's wrong. `std::remove` and `std:remove_if` operate on **sequences**. The standard doesn't directly impose any requirements on anything past the end of the sequence. The effect may well be that those elements were moved-from, so will have whatever result moving from them produces. Yes, when the sequence comes from a container, the size of the container is not changed. That's because the algorithm doesn't operate on containers, but on sequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's `std::remove_if`, not `std::move_if`. It simply removes all elements that return true from the `test` function. Now, why the extra `b`s? Well, you're not supposed to be seeing them. `std::remove_if` returns an iterator marking the new end of the sequence, and you're supposed to use the return value to resize the container accordingly. So let's say we have a string `"Hello, World!"` and we need to remove all `l`'s from it. Here's an example program to show one way of doing this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a = "Hello, World!";
    a.resize(std::distance(
        a.begin(),
        std::remove_if(a.begin(), a.end(), [](char c){return c == 'l';})
    ));
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
Heo, Word!
```

Comment: The idiomatic way is to use `a.erase(std::remove_if(...), std::end(a))`. Your approach works, but not every container has `resize`. The `erase` approach works for all containers which don't have a fixed size.

Comment: I am new to C++ programming and first time seeing Predicate written like this **[](char c){return c == 'l';}**  , I can not understand how the function header is written, can anyone tell the name of concept used in writing this? @mediocrevegetable1

Comment: @tarunmali it's called a lambda, basically an anonymous function that you can put inside other functions. Feel free to do some research on it to learn more. Till then, you can take a look at this program which does the same thing as the one I've got in my answer but uses a normal function instead of a lambda: https://godbolt.org/z/va68s9jMn

Comment: @tarunmali see [Lambda expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda)

Comment: The return value doesn't mark "the new end of the container". It marks the new end of the **sequence**. It doesn't know or care that this particular sequence is provided by a container.

Comment: @PeteBecker you're right, edited to clarify :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux which one is faster using erase or resize(if it is available in the container), referred this question but can't really find the answer

Comment: @tarunmali I'm not sure there will be a big difference. `resize` could just as well be implemented in terms of `erase`. If there is any difference at all, it will be insignificant, and it will depend on the actual implementation.

Comment: @tarunmali Just did a benchmark of `resize`, `.erase` and `std::erase_if` because I was curious, and according to [quick-bench (GNU libstdc++ & GCC 10.2)](https://quick-bench.com/q/PCfd6skxEkczQ8TIXcyEAe2rNFg), `.erase` and `std::erase_if` are about the same while `resize` is apparently 1.1 times faster. I would still probably do `std::erase_if` because it looks more intuitive, and if not that then probably `.erase` for consistency with other containers that don't support `resize`, and because it seems to be convention as opposed to `resize`.

Answer (score 3):

> According to my understanding so far it should move all the a characters to the right of b

Almost. It does the opposite: It (sort of) moves the b characters to the left of a. To be more accurate, it "move assigns" over the removed elements.

Thus, the elements on the left are the b's moved **from** the right (over the a's that were on the left), and the elements on the right are the b's that were moved **to** the left. Since moving a char is same as copying i.e. it doesn't modify the argument that is moved from, this leaves both left and right elements being b's.

Since the intended use case of the algorithm is to **remove** a's, it's not a problem that no a's remain in the container. Note that with different inputs, some a's may remain in the right end of the container. The elements at the right are either remnants of elements that were moved to left (not a's), or elements that weren't moved since they are to be removed (a's).

P.S. Instead of the previously idiomatic pattern shown in GregReese's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67710380/2079303) and in François Andrieux's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67710057/how-exactly-remove-if-works/67710435#comment119681733_67710217), you can now in C++20 (or in future, given that you've tagged C++17) use:

```
std::erase_if(A, test);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're correct in how `remove_if` works. However, it returns an iterator that points to the first of the removed elements, which is the same as one past the last of the elements that were not removed. You then need to delete the elements that were removed to get the answer you want. Thus in the function`isPalindrome`, replace your `remove_if` line with

```
   const auto new_end = remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), test);
   A.erase(new_end, A.end());
```

Then you'll get `bbbbb`.

This pattern of calling `remove_if` followed by `erase` occurs often. The two lines are usually combined into one and that is known as the "remove-erase idiom". In your case replace you `remove_if` line with

```
   A.erase( remove_if(A.begin(), A.end(), test), A.end() );
```

Comment: No, the returned iterator does not point at the first of the removed elements. The removed elements have been overwritten; they no longer exist.

Comment: My bad. It should just be "However, it returns an iterator that points to one past the last of the elements that were not removed."

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm just moves or copies (depending on used iterators) elements equal to 'b' to positions where elements equal to 'a' are stored if this is required.

It does not swap elements of the container.

Comment: Re: "It does not swap elements of the container." In fact, it doesn't know or care that this particular **sequence** is provided by a container. It operates on the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I've made the same point in several comments, but I think it needs to be addressed in more detail.

Algorithms like `std::remove` and `std::remove_if` apply to **sequences**, i.e., elements designated by a pair of iterators. The first iterator points at the first element of the sequence and the second iterator points past the end of the sequence of elements. Effectively, the algorithms move or copy elements from later in the sequence to overwrite elements that are being removed.

Note that the previous paragraph does not use the word **container**. A container is one way of managing a sequence of elements, but it is not the only way. Algorithms don't know anything about containers. `remove` and `remove_if` can't change the size of a container that they know nothing about.

What you see when you look at the container after passing its elements to `remove` or `remove_if` is the modified sequence (from the beginning of the container up to the element pointed at by the iterator that the algorithm returned), followed by whatever is left over. For simple types like `char` this residue is probably whatever was there to begin with. For more complex types that have non-trivial move-assignment operators, the residue consists of whatever the move-assignment leaves behind. For types defined in the C++ standard library, that means that the residue consists of objects in an unspecified but valid state. For types defined somewhere other than the standard library they're left in whatever state the designer chose.